# I'm trying to target the JavaScript Window Alert OK button from a VBScript

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

The VBScript is being run from Task Scheduler on the server and an Internet Explorer Object. When I try to use SENDKEYS Enter, the Internet Explorer isn't the currently selected window, so the Enter key isn't entered in there. So I'm trying to hit the OK button by using "GetElementById" using the IE Object and I've been looking pretty extensively, but I can't find the name/id/class of the OK Button on the JavaScript Windows Alert to .Click/.Submit on it. Does anyone have a workaround/solution to this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JS, `alert` is a DOM method, it's not a part of JS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBScript set focus on a window in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985997/vbscript-set-focus-on-a-window-in-ie) -- from 2011 hehe)

Comment: finding the old stuff can be the hardest sometimes, thank you, I'm hoping that this'll work :)